# What does “Something” mean ontologically?

Tags: ontology, philosophy-of-language, semantics, language

Many refer to the question of there is something rather than nothing by assuming that something refers to the universe.

Is the word “something” an existential quantification in this context? Is something a word that English speakers can use without limitation, referring to entities or states of affairs or whatnot?

Definitions of this word make it very difficult to pin point the true nature of this word. It holds so much significance ontologically that an understanding of the meaning of something would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: Does it have to have a lot of ontological significance? According to the empirical research of the Natural Semantic Metalanguage project, SOMETHING is a semantic prime: a core concept shared by all human languages, which cannot be reduced, and cannot be more clearly defined than the word itself. SOMETHING is a fundamental concept upon which we build other ideas.

Comment: [Existence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/) and [Being](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger/#BeiTim) are the basic concepts of Ontology (or Metaphysics).

Comment: To say "there is something which is P" amounts to asserting the existence of an entity (thing, object) which has property P. Thus, the elucidation of "something" amounts to the existence of [Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object/) and [Properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/).

Comment: Because human perceptive range is limited; for example, we can only hold a distinct number of items in mind at once, say picturing in the minds-eye, ten years, etc. the concept 'something' represents an unquantifiable identity, like something wonderful. CS

Comment: What English speakers can use is entirely up to them, and they certainly do not align their use with formal logic or philosophical distinctions. Questions about the prevailing use of words are more suited for [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Conifold so do English speakers not use existential quantification when they say SOMETHING?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so what definition of THING would SOMETHING assume in this context?

Comment: Most English speakers have no idea what existential quantification is, so no. And many uses of "something" certainly do not refer to any delineated domain of "things" (as quantification requires), e.g. as in "we have to do something". Just because the letter string "thing" occurs within the letter string "something" does not mean there is any relation between their referents.

Comment: @Conifold so is there an unrestricted meaning of SOMETHING that English speakers use in phrases like “why is there something rather than nothing” which is completely dependent on the context? This is what I think the answer is but I can’t find literature to support it

Comment: @Conifold moreover, how do English speakers form their meaning of SOMETHING if not for subconscious quantification of some sort?

Comment: The first is a question for English or Linguistics SE, and the second is for Psychology SE. On theories of quantification in natural language alternative to the standard predicate calculus see [Ben-Yami Logic & Natural Language](https://publications.ceu.edu/publications/ben-yami/2004/15107).

Comment: @Conifold thanks. The thing is that folks in English SE have said that SOMETHING has to do with existential quantification. It appears your view point is concerning the logic of natural languages. Many others have referred to SOMETHING as having a very close relationship to existential quantification. Do you disagree with the premise of this or just the fact that English speakers are not aware of the name “existential quantification”?

Comment: I can't speak to what others have in mind by “existential quantification”. But the idea that use of "something" in natural languages can be stuffed into the so named concept of the standard predicate calculus is a big stretch, to say the least.